# Parse JSON from PHP by Javascript and Push the values into array dynamically

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, json, windows-8

i got an array :

```
var sampleitems =[];
```

i get json data from url which returns values

```
 WinJS.xhr({
        type: "GET",
        url: "http://some_webpage.php", 

    }).then(function (success) { 
// DYNAMICALLY PUSH CONTENTS TO ARRAY 'sampleitems'
    }, 
  function (error) {
      document.getElementById("check").innerText = "vada pochu";
  }
```

i need the array to look like:

```
var sampleitems = [
{ key: "group1", title: "Group Title: 1", subtitle: "Group Subtitle: 1", backgroundImage: darkGray, description: groupDescription } ];
```

How can i add values to the sample items dynamically and how my PHP page should return JSON in which format ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should look at PHP's [JSON_ENCODE()](http://php.net/json_encode)
function. The code below should output the JSON that you need (I haven't checked that it works).

```
$sampleitems=array(
 array(
  'key'=>'group1',
  'title'=>'Group Title: 1',
  ...
 )
);

echo json_encode($sampleitems);
```

Answer (score 0):

sampleitems.push({ key: "group1", title: "Group Title: 1", subtitle: "Group Subtitle: 1", backgroundImage: darkGray, description: groupDescription });

Comment: I did that, but how to send json from php and how to get by JS to perform push operation ?

Answer (score 0):

make an array an perform json_encode like:

```
$sampleitems = array(
        'key' => 'group1',
        'title' => 'Group Title: 1',
        'subtitle' => 'Group Subtitle: 1',
        'backgroundImage' => 'darkGray',
        'description' => 'groupDescription'
    );
    echo '['.json_encode($sampleitems).']';
```

result:

```
[{"key":"group1","title":"Group Title: 1","subtitle":"Group Subtitle: 1","backgroundImage":"darkGray","description":"groupDescription"}]
```

Comment: how to get this is Javascript / push the item ?

Comment: var sampleitems = <?php echo '['.json_encode($sampleitems).']'; ?> write this in JS